# Google Analytics - How to set up Google Analytics for Email Open-rate Tracking?

Tags: google-analytics, email-analytics

**I have a requirement of tracking email open rates.**

So I decided to use Google Analytics for this purpose. Most of the online tutorials were using "Google Pixel Tracking" for this purpose. The idea is used to add a Tracking script  on the IMG source in the Email. The Image (1x1 pixel) will be uploaded on the GA server. When the User opens the email, the image will be downloaded and the GA server will record the details.

**However, In the current version of Google Analytics, I am not able to achieve this. There is no option to upload a "pixel"**

Things have changed in the recent version of Google Analytics. If somebody has got this working, please let me know how you did it.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with Google Analytics through **Measurement Protocol**, placing an image tag within the email.

```
...
<img src=
"https://www.google-analytics.com/collect?v=1&tid=ABC&cid=555&aip=1&t=event&ec=email&ea=open&dp=%2Femail%2Fnewsletter1&dt=My%20Newsletter">
...
</body>
</html>
```

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/email